# Как зафиксировать ярлыки на рабочем столе в Windows10 Виндовс 10 в определенных местах, чтобы не сбрасывались?

Tags: windows

У меня на рабочем месте ярлыки должны быть в определенных местах. У меня 2 монитора. И часто ярлыки сбрасываются, и все в одну кучу сбиваются в правую часть основного монитора. Как их зафиксировать, подскажите, желательно может онлайн сервис был, чтобы можно было развернуть эти ярлыки в нужных местах . Или на крайний случай програмку какую установить. Буду рад любой информации.   А то получается сбросились ярлыки , потом по 10 минут ищу нужный файл в этой всей кучи , такое ощущение что нес инструмент в руках и все уронил в одну кучу  ,а потом разгребаю  , ну вы понимаете ))))

Comment: Например можно использовать [Fences](https://www.stardock.com/products/fences/).

Comment: На Linux-е тоже, черт побери, такое вечно творится.